# Navigation Bar used on JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/)

Tags: javascript, user-interface, navigation, jsfiddle

Quick question. Whats the navigation bar used on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). I thought it was Bootstrap but haven't been able to see any examples which look like that in other bootstrap themes. Would appreciate link to any open source code if available. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `bootstrap`. Instead it is created using basic `HTML` elements and customs styles.

Below is snapshot for better illustration.
You can add [wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?hl=en) extension to find out what frameworks/ libraries have been used in the webpage.

[image: Jsfiddle DOM structure]

Comment: Thank you! Certainly helpful.